Storing temp strings in memory for the duration of an active window in Rust Tauri implementation
So, assuming we want to store some reusable strings in memory for when we invoke a Rust function from frontend when the window instance is still active, how would be do that?
In particular, when we launch the program, a dynamic session ID will be initiated that we want to retrieve when invoking certain functions. How can we store this temp ID so that it is only accessible when the window instance is active, and purged from memory when the program is closed so that the next time the program opens, a new session ID is loaded?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
